# Logging an exception if and only if it was not caught later by try and except

Tags: python, logging, try-catch

I have a class in which I log errors and raise them. However, I have different functions which expect that error.

Now, even if these functions except the error properly, it is still logged. This leads to confusing log files in which multiple conflicting entries can be seen. For example:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename = "./log")
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def foo_error(self):
        logger.error("You have done something very stupid!")
        raise RuntimeError("You have done something very stupid!")

    def foo_except(self):
        try:
            self.foo_error()
        except RuntimeError as error: 
            logger.info("It was not so stupid after all!") 


Foo = Foo()
Foo.foo_except()
```

Here, both messages show up in `"./log"`. Preferably, I would like to suppress the first error log message if it is caught later on.

I have not seen an answer anywhere else. Maybe the way I am doing things suggests bad design. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really ask Python whether an exception will be caught lateron. So your only choice is to log only after you know whether the exception was caught or not.

One possible solution (though I'm not sure if this will work in your context):

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename = "./log")
logger = logging.getLogger()

class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def foo_error(self):
        # logger.error("You have done something very stupid!")
        raise RuntimeError("You have done something very stupid!")

    def foo_except(self):
        try:
            self.foo_error()
        except RuntimeError as error:
            logger.warning("It was not so stupid after all!")

try:
    Foo = Foo()
    Foo.foo_except()
    Foo.foo_error()
except Exception as exc:
    if isinstance(exc, RuntimeError):
        logger.error("%s",  exc)
    raise
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more thinking and several failed attempts, i arrived at the following answer.

Firstly, as @gelonida mentioned:

> You cannot really ask Python whether an exception will be caught later on.

This implies that a log entry which also raises an exception has to be written, because if the exception is not caught later on, the log entry is wiped out and missing from the file.

So instead of trying to control which log message gets written to file, we should implement a way to delete voided log messages from the file.

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename = "./log")
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def foo_error(self):
        logger.error("You have done something very stupid!")
        raise RuntimeError("You have done something very stupid!")

    def foo_except(self):
        try:
            self.foo_error()
        except RuntimeError as error: 
            logger.info("It was not so stupid after all!") 


Foo = Foo()
Foo.foo_except()
```

Following that logic we should replace in the original example above the line `logger.info("It was not so stupid after all!")` with a function that deletes the last committed log message and logs the correct one instead!

One way to achieve this is to modify the logging class and add two components. Namely a log record history and a `FileHandler` which supports deletion of log records. Let's start with the log record history.

```py
class RecordHistory:
    def __init__(self):
        self._record_history = []

    def write(self, record):
        self._record_history.append(record)

    def flush(self):
        pass

    def get(self):
        return self._record_history[-1]

    def pop(self):
        return self._record_history.pop()
```

This is basically a data container which implements the write and flush methods alongside some other conveniences. The write and flush methods are required by `logging.StreamHandler`. For more information visit the `logging.handlers` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#module-logging.handlers).

Next, we modify the existing `logging.FileHandler` to support the `revoke` method. This method allows us to delete a specific log record.

```py
import re

class RevokableFileHandler(logging.FileHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def revoke(self, record):
        with open(self.baseFilename, mode="r+") as log:
            substitute = re.sub(rf"{record}", "", log.read(), count=1)
            log.seek(0)
            log.write(substitute)
            log.truncate()
```

Finally, we modify the `Logger` class. Note however that we cannot inherit from `logging.Logger` directly as stated [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLoggerClass). Additionally, we add a `logging.StreamHandler` which pushes log records to our `RecordHistory` object. Also we implement a `addRevokableHandler` method which registers all handlers that support revoking records.

```py
import logging

class Logger(logging.getLoggerClass()):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

        self.revokable_handlers = []
        self.record_history = RecordHistory()

        stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=self.record_history)
        stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        self.addHandler(stream_handler)

    def addRevokableHandler(self, handler):
        self.revokable_handlers.append(handler)
        super().addHandler(handler)

    def pop_and_log(self, level, msg):
        record = self.record_history.pop()
        for handler in self.revokable_handlers:
            handler.revoke(record)
        self.log(level, msg)
```

This leads to the following solution in the original code:

```py
logging.setLoggerClass(Logger)

logger = logging.getLogger("root")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

file_handler = RevokableFileHandler("./log")
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addRevokableHandler(file_handler)


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def foo_error(self):
        logger.error("You have done something very stupid!")
        raise RuntimeError("You have done something very stupid!")

    def foo_except(self):
        try:
            self.foo_error()
        except KeyError as error:
            logger.pop_and_log(logging.INFO, "It was not so stupid after all!")


Foo = Foo()
Foo.foo_except()
```

Hopefully this lengthy answer can be of use to someone. Though it is still not clear to me if logging errors and info messages in such a way is considered bad code design.